# Selector returns different values jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got:

```
j=0;
an = $("#thumbSlider" + j + " a").eq(1);
ap = $("#thumbSlider" + j + " a").eq(0);

jQuery("div#thumbSlider" + j + " a").each(function(z) { 
  jQuery(this).bind("click", function(){
    ad = jQuery("#thumbSlider" + j + " a").eq(1);
    alert(ad.length);
```

.
.

The first alert returns 1, but the second, on click, returns 0.
Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
jQuery(this).bind("click", function(){
  alert(this.length);
```

Not be what you're looking for?

Comment: Not really, I want to get the next and prev elements, "1" was just an example.
alert(jQuery(this).next().length); returns 0.

I've got 8 links and 2 prev/next buttons, when I click on a link I want to set the prev/next values so that when I click on the buttons it will point to that link.

But still, I can not get why it returns 2 different values, 1 in the main script, but 0 in the click function.